# Ubuntu 14.04, Plug in HDMI to external monitor causes a log in - out loop

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

- Model: MSI GT70 2PE
- CPU: Intel Core i7-4810MQ
- RAM: 16.0GB
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX880M
- SSD: Samsung 840 EV0 1TB
- OS:  Windows 8.1 Pro Dual Boot with Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

When I plug my external FLATRON IPS236 27" Monitor in via HDMI in Windows it works fine. Regardless if I plug it in before I boot, or afterwards.

The first time I plugged it into my Ubuntu OS (I plugged it in before I booted into it) it came up with an error with something like "Must run in low graphics mode, please wait for screen to reboot" and then my external monitor went black, and my laptop display went to a black screen with the little white underscore thing in the top left corner (don't know what that is actually called).

It never refreshed so I rebooted. Since it has never given that message.

When I plug it in after I boot, it will log me out, my external monitor goes black, and then my laptop monitor will continuously blink on and off every second or so. Every time it does, it will take me to the log in screen. If I try to type in my password it will begin to enter it but the next time it refreshes there is nothing in the password entry box, so I believe it is continuously going to sleep and waking up, thus requiring me to reenter my password every time.

I have tried setting my laptop display's resolution to 800x600 rather than 1920x1080 to get it in a "low graphics mode" but that doesn't seem to help.

Plugging monitors in via VGA does seem to work. Any advice is greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a graphics driver issue. I would recommend you try downloading the latest drivers for Linux from the nvidia website. As the default nvidia drivers in Ubuntu are open source by downloading drivers from the nvidia site you will get completely different drivers than the ones you are currently using and it is likely that this will fix the issue you are experiencing.